# Call value of prepare/binded values

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to call the `$userId` value at the same time of form submit.  I think my only options are going through `$stmt->bind_param` but I don't know how to call the value.

```
    // Record a Payment Received
    if (isset($_POST['submit']) && $_POST['submit'] == 'recordPay') {
        // User Validations
        if($_POST['paymentDate'] == '') {
            $msgBox = alertBox($payDateReq, "<i class='fa fa-times-circle'></i>", "danger");
        } else if($_POST['paymentFor'] == '') {
            $msgBox = alertBox($payForReq, "<i class='fa fa-times-circle'></i>", "danger");
        } else if($_POST['amountPaid'] == '') {
            $msgBox = alertBox($payAmtReq, "<i class='fa fa-times-circle'></i>", "danger");
        } else if($_POST['paymentType'] == '') {
            $msgBox = alertBox($payTypeReq, "<i class='fa fa-times-circle'></i>", "danger");
        } else {
            $paymentDate = htmlspecialchars($_POST['paymentDate']);
            $paymentFor = htmlspecialchars($_POST['paymentFor']);
            $amountPaid = htmlspecialchars($_POST['amountPaid']);
            $paymentType = htmlspecialchars($_POST['paymentType']);
            $rentMonth = htmlspecialchars($_POST['rentMonth']);
            $rentYear = htmlspecialchars($_POST['rentYear']);
            $notes = htmlspecialchars($_POST['notes']);
            $propertyName = htmlspecialchars($_POST['propertyName']);
            $leaseId = htmlspecialchars($_POST['leaseId']);
            $userId = htmlspecialchars($_POST['userId']);

            if ($_POST['penaltyFee'] == '') { $penaltyFee = null; } else { $penaltyFee = htmlspecialchars($_POST['penaltyFee']); }
            if ($rentMonth == '...') {
                $isRent = '0';
                $rntMonth = null;
            } else {
                $isRent = '1';
                $rntMonth = $rentMonth;
            }
            if ($rentYear == '') {
                $rntYear = null;
            } else {
                $rntYear = $rentYear;
            }

            $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("
                                INSERT INTO
                                    payments(
                                        leaseId,
                                        propertyId,
                                        adminId,
                                        userId,
                                        paymentDate,
                                        amountPaid,
                                        penaltyFee,
                                        paymentFor,
                                        paymentType,
                                        isRent,
                                        rentMonth,
                                        rentYear,
                                        notes,
                                        lastUpdated,
                                        ipAddress
                                    ) VALUES (
                                        ?,
                                        ?,
                                        ?,
                                        ?,
                                        ?,
                                        ?,
                                        ?,
                                        ?,
                                        ?,
                                        ?,
                                        ?,
                                        ?,
                                        ?,
                                        NOW(),
                                        ?
                                        ()

            ");
            $stmt->bind_param('ssssssssssssss',
                $leaseId,
                $propertyId,
                $rs_adminId,
                $userId,
                $paymentDate,
                $amountPaid,
                $penaltyFee,
                $paymentFor,
                $paymentType,
                $isRent,
                $rntMonth,
                $rntYear,
                $notes,
                $ipAddress
            );
            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->close();

I then want to take the `$userID` and associate it with another `userId` in the `users` table so I can echo the `primaryPhone` column in `users` table.  I only want to echo the `primaryPhone` from the data submitted on the form.

>1. Call `$userId` from `$stmt->bind_param`
>2. Associate the `$userId` with userId from `users` table to pull `primaryPhone`
```

Edit: This is the code I'm using and its loading the page, just not returning the value. I placed this code under `$stmt->execute();`

```
   if ($stmt->execute()){
                $qryPhone = mysqli_query("SELECT primaryPhone FROM users WHERE userId = '$userID'");
                echo $qryPhone;
                }
```

and that loads the page, but doesn't give me the primaryPhone value.  However when I use

```
if ($stmt->execute()){
            echo $userId;
            }
```

Then I get the userId I need, but I can't do anything with it.

EDIT: FIXED.

I put this code in after `$stmt->close();`

```
$qryPhone = "SELECT primaryPhone FROM users WHERE userId=".(int)$userId;
 $query  = mysqli_query($mysqli, $qryPhone);
while ($fetch = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
        $primaryPhone = '+1'.decryptIt($fetch['primaryPhone']);
        echo $primaryPhone;
    }
```

Comment: Prepare statement, bind parameter,execute and get the result. What's holding you back from doing this? What's the issue?

Comment: Whats holding me back is the syntax because whenever I try doing it the script breaks.

Comment: Please explain *script breaks*. Does it show any error?

Comment: Please check my edit

Comment: Ah, good catch! :) @devpro

Comment: @JoeElia Just as devpro commented, what's this `()` doing there in prepare statement? Are you sure the values get inserted in `payments` table properly?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure the values get populated correctly.  Not sure why thats there.  I solved my issue by putting this code in after the $stmt->close(); (SEE EDIT)

Comment: @JoeElia Glad the issue is resolved, but like I said, don't mix the procedural and object oriented style of `mysqli`, it's a bad practice.

Comment: Im new to programming.  Thanks for the tip though.  I will do some research on procedural and object oriented.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `mysqli_query()` takes atleast two parameters, first is your connection handler and second is your query, like this: `mysqli_query($connection, $query)`

Here's the reference:

- [`mysqli_query()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php#refsect1-mysqli.query-description)

Second, don't mix the procedural and object oriented style of `mysqli`.

And finally comes to your issue, first prepare the statement, bind necessary parameter, execute the query, bind the result and finally fetch the value.

Here's the reference:

- [`mysqli::prepare()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php)

So your code should be like this:

```
if ($stmt->execute()){
    // create a prepared statement
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT primaryPhone FROM users WHERE userId=?");

    // bind parameter
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $userID);

    // execute query
    $stmt->execute();

    // bind result variables
    $stmt->bind_result($primaryPhone);

    // fetch value
    $stmt->fetch();

    // echo primaryPhone
    echo $primaryPhone;
}
```